# foreach loop not working for activeRecord yii

Tags: php, yii, foreach

I am using Yii rights extension. In this extension there is a table named `authassignment`. I have created a model for this table. I have fetched the records as

```
$developers=  Authassignment::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'itemname'=>'developer'
        ));
```

It is returning correct records.Now i want to iterate using `foreach` loop.I am doing like

```
foreach($developers as $item){
            CVarDumper::Dump($item,100,true);
            die();
            $ids=$ids.$item->userid;
            $ids=$ids.',';

        }
```

as seen above when i dump the value it shows `developer`. Developer is the value of the attribute of table. But obviously it is wrong it should return me first record in the array of records.
I have used foreach before but this happened for the first time. 
Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's obvious. because you use `die()`. `die()` cause break out from loop. no need to use foreach for var_dump. you can easily do this:

```
die(var_dump($developers ));
```

Comment: I am not using foreach to check the records. I have to do something else but i cant access $item->userid. it says non object. Yes i know how to dump and i have done it earlier. I just want to dump in the foreach loop to see the single record.

Comment: I don't realize what your exact problem. Is your problem just "Trying to get property of non object" error?

Comment: yes you can say that. But it is more problem of single record in foreach loop.

Comment: I think at least one of the $items is null, or has a null userid.

Comment: no that is not the case. I have checked that earlier.